# Is there a way for bash to know home directory without $HOME variable

Tags: c, shell, environment-variables

I found that bash, even if I unset HOME, USER, LOGNAME environment variables and write `cd ~`,  still knows the path for HOME directory. How does that happen?

Comment: ~ is nicely explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/146697/266162)

Comment: It depends on the operating system, but (eg) `~` resolves to `$HOME` or `getent passwd <user>` that will get the home dir from `/etc/passwd`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C code can call functions like `getpwnaw`, `getpwuid`, `getpwent` to get info about a user.

From Bash's source code, in `lib/tilde/shell.c`, see line 69:

```
 59 char *
 60 get_home_dir (void)
 61 {
 62   static char *home_dir = (char *)NULL;
 63   struct passwd *entry;
 64
 65   if (home_dir)
 66     return (home_dir);
 67
 68 #if defined (HAVE_GETPWUID)
 69   entry = getpwuid (getuid ());
 70   if (entry)
 71     home_dir = savestring (entry->pw_dir);
 72 #endif
 73
 74 #if defined (HAVE_GETPWENT)
 75   endpwent ();          /* some systems need this */
 76 #endif
 77
 78   return (home_dir);
 79 }
```

And in `lib/tilde/tilde.c`, see line 386:

```
335 char *
336 tilde_expand_word (const char *filename)
337 {
338   char *dirname, *expansion, *username;
339   int user_len;
340   struct passwd *user_entry;
...
384   dirname = (char *)NULL;
385 #if defined (HAVE_GETPWNAM)
386   user_entry = getpwnam (username);
387 #else
388   user_entry = 0;
389 #endif
...
```

Comment: `user_entry = 0;`? And that is why `NULL` pointers and "null pointer constants" have gotten so complex in C.  Programmers who are too clever and ***wrongly*** believe "`NULL` is just zero so I'll use `0` instead of the correct `NULL`."  Never mind the `(char *)` cast from `NULL` is not needed in C.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: '*wrongly believe "NULL is just zero so I'll use 0 instead of the correct NULL."*' no so wrong anymore since C<something>(99?)

Comment: @alk The entire reason that C99 created the concept of "null pointer constants" was ***bad code*** that assumed `NULL` is zero.  It's a [sop](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/sop) to poor programmers with low standards, and now we have to live with the complexity of `NULL` and "null pointer constants".

Comment: @AndrewHenle The NULL pointer is required to compare equal to zero constant.

Comment: @iBug You missed my point.  The `NULL` pointer is required to compare equal to a zero constant **BECAUSE too many incompetent programmers wrote bad code that incorrectly assumed "`NULL` must be zero."** That's *why* the standard was modified and made a lot more complex than it had to be. It's no different from incompetent programmers who assume "A pointer is an `int`"  That this is the `bash` source code means there's a high likelihood that the setting of the pointer to a literal zero predates C99 and contributed to that needless complexity.  The `(char *)` cast from `NULL` is also bad.